# Inserting Unicode String to SQL Server via R

Tags: r, sql-server, unicode

I am trying to insert some Unicode string to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 from R Studio, but it does not work.
For example, "綫" , "Араб" , "❤" ...

And, here is my code:

```
library("RODBC")
sdb <- odbcConnect("R_SQLServ", uid="uid", pwd="pwd")
sqlQuery(sdb,"insert into test(someWord) VALUES(N'❤')")
odbcClose(sdb)
```

However, the value displayed on SQL database table is :

```
someWord
<U+2764>
```

Settings, background, or something I have tried and tested are as below:

> sessionInfo()   R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) Platform:
>   x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build
>   7601) Service Pack 1
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong S.A.R..950 
>   LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong S.A.R..950    [3]
>   LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong S.A.R..950 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong S.A.R..950
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] RODBC_1.3-15 tmcn_0.2-12
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_3.4.3
>   tools_3.4.3    yaml_2.1.14

- The data type of the column was set to nvarchar(MAX).
- In the R console, all of the characters are displayed correctly, but on the right side of R Studio panel with all my variables at the Environment tab, the variable that stored "❤" is displayed as `"<U+2764>"`
- It works when I execute the SQL command `INSERT INTO test (someWord) VALUES (N'❤')` in SQL Server Management Studio.
- I have tried resetting the locale setting on R Studio as different languages, either the same as my system language or not.

Comment: This might help localize the problem (perhaps it has nothing to do with SQL Server): The U+hex notation is for Unicode codepoints—almost exclusively for discussion and debugging display purposes. U+2764 is, in fact, a such a represention for ❤. The question remains, is ❤ being converted to <U+2764> before storage or is it simply the representation chosen for your particular display panel? Try a minimal example that doesn't involve storage.

Comment: Yes, I guess that is the problem from R. Some of the unicode characters auto change to the codepoints string internally. One more sample for your reference, when i write it to a txt file by writeLines('綫', "test.txt"), it still display codepoints string. But when i use writeLines('綫', "test.txt",useBytes=T), it's works. So is there any similar parameters like useBytes=T in R - SQL inserting query